# Python xml.etree.ElemenTree, getting HTML entities

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I am trying to analyze xml data, and encountered an issue with regard to HTML entities when I use

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse(my_xml_file)
root = tree.getroot()
for regex_rule in root.findall('.//regex_rule'):
  print(regex_rule.get('input')) #this ".get()" method turns &lt; into <, but I want to get &lt; as written
  print(regex_rule.get('input') == "(?&lt;!\S)hello(?!\S)") #prints out false because ElementTree's get method turns &lt; into < , is that right?
```

And here is the xml file contents:

```
<rules>
<regex_rule input="(?&lt;!\S)hello(?!\S)" output="world"/>
</rules>
```

I would appreciate if anybody can direct me to getting the string as is from the xml attribute for the input, without converting

```
&lt;
```

into

```
<
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`xml.etree.ElementTree` is doing exactly the standards-compliant thing, which is to decode XML character entities with the understanding that they do in fact encode the referenced character and should be interpreted as such.

The preferred course of action if you do need to encode the literal `&lt;` is to change your input file to use `&amp;lt;` instead (i.e. we XML-encode the `&`).

If you can't change your input file format then you'll probably need to use a different module, or write your own parser: `xml.etree.ElementTree` translates entities well before you can do anything meaningful with the output.

Comment: Thanks for your input. It seems that I am out of luck, using xml.etree.ElementTree. I will resort to some kind of other creative solutions. (I am in an environment where I can't easily install other modules like lxml, etc). I am basically checking rules that exist in xml and json files. In json files, there is no html entity, and there shouldn't be. I will accept your response as the answer. Thank you.